# div slide effect

Tags: javascript

i need to slide a div down and then up on an event, how can i do this in java script

Comment: You can't do this that simply with vanilla javascript, but most of the common frameworks have an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** 
**[I created this demo for you :)](http://jsbin.com/ideme)**

You can do that **easily** with **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)** function of JQuery:

```
<div id="hello">Hello World</div>
<a href="#" id="link">Toggle Div</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(){
      $('#hello').slideToggle();
      return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: slideToggle() have to define?

Comment: borother sorry to say, infact i have never used jquery before, do i need some spcial library to add,or any thing special else?

Comment: @vakas: yes brother, you need to download the jquery from here http://jquery.com/ and include in your page.

Comment: i have added this
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript\jquery.js">
    $(function(){
    alert('hi');
    $('#link').click(function(){
      $('#hello').slideToggle();
      return false;
    })
});
    </script> 

but nt wrking

Comment: @vakas: see the code of the example demo link i posted in my answer, you can use like that.

Comment: thanx brother its wrking now, can u also plz tell me any method to shake the page, i want to prompt the user,dat something has happend.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you check out [jQuery/UI/Effects/Slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

Comment: but i want to use it simply by javascript

Comment: There is no simple way to do it without using a library like jQuery. Using jQuery will actually make things very simple whereas rolling your own code to do this would be very complex in comparison.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but worth noting for slide up/down he doesn't need jQuery UI, just jQuery core will do.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend look at what JQuery or another javascript library does, (maybe even AJAX control toolkit for .NET, which has JS components) and examine the JS file, and replicate the feature yourself...

I will say it probably isn't that easy to replicate yourself, meaning that the logic is pretty complex.

HTH.